# Why if $H$ be non abelian group , then $ \frac {H}{Z(G) \cap H} $ is non abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.

Why if $H$ be non abelian group , then $ \frac {H}{Z(G) \cap  H} $ is non abelian?

Comment: This is not true in general, as already answered. It is, however, true that $\frac{H}{H \cap Z(G)}$ is not cyclic when $H$ is non-Abelian.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is true. You should try with a "small" non abelian group $G$ and $H:=G$.

> Take $G:=\mathbb{D}_4$ the dihedral group with $8$ elements and $H:=G$. Then $Z(G)\cap H=Z(G)$ is of order $2$ whence $\frac{H}{Z(G)\cap H}=\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ is of order $4$ and whence is abelian. But $G=H$ is not abelian.

Edit : about the remark of Geoff Robinson, $\frac{H}{H\cap Z(G)}$ cannot be cyclic when $H$ is non abelian.

The idea is to use the fact that $H\cap Z(G)\leq Z(H)$.

> When $H$ is non abelian, one can show (classical exercise) that $H/Z(H)$ is not cyclic (if it were cyclic then any element of $H$ would be written $\gamma^kz$ with $z\in Z(H)$ and $\gamma$ a fixed element of $H$). Now, since $H\cap Z(G)\leq Z(H)$ we get $H/Z(H)\leq H/(H\cap Z(G))$ since $H/Z(H)$ is not cyclic $H/(H\cap Z(G))$ cannot be cyclic either (all subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic groups).

Comment: Why if H be non abelian group , then H / (Z(G)∩H)  is non cyclic?

Comment: @ghazale, Try to use the hint before looking the proof.